# Thermal conductivity of a binary gas mixture

Tags: thermodynamics, ideal-gas, thermal-conductivity

I want to estimate the thermal conductivity of binary gas mixture, say water vapor+nitrogen. I assume the mixture as ideal gas. The molar fraction and thermal conductivities of the components are known.
Could you give me a hint or point me to a classical reference.

Comment: Are you sure that you want the thermal conductivity of a gas? In most cases, it's not a very meaningful concept or relevant since transport of heat energy through gases is usually much more due to the bulk convective flow of the gas than due to molecule-on-molecule collisions.

Comment: @SamuelWeir, I do want to know the thermal conductivity of a gas mixture :) You are right, the thermal conductivity is indeed small usually. However, the relative order of magnitude should be more relevant for the heat conduction in the case of liquid in contact with a gas. For example, $k_{helium}=0.153$ W/(m.K), which is nearly equal to that of the liquid ethanol.